# Date transformation in Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

What is the easier way to compare dates in a different format in Oracle?
Example:
In the first table, I have a date the format: "2017/09/15 03:14:13".
The second table contains data with the format: "15-SEP-17"

I would like to compare these dates like Table1.column>Table2.column

One way is a well-known solution with to_date(to_char()), but I am curious if there is any simpler way. Any thought?

Comment: what is the data type of both columns?

Comment: "*but I am curious if there is any simpler way*" - yes there is: use a proper `DATE` (or `TIMESTAMP`) column then you don't need to worry about "formats". Storing dates (or numbers) in `VARCHAR` columns is a **really**, really bad idea

Comment: @Boneist that's a good point cause one column is varchar2 second is date type. Ok, there is no simple way to do it better/faster. Conversion is required anyway. Thanks guys!

Comment: if one is in varchar2 format, you would need to do something like `Table1.column > to_date(Table2.column, '<whatever the format mask is>')` with the to_date on the column that's a varchar2 and with the relevant format mask.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle date have no format at all. If you wish to compare dates you may use something like `date1 < date2`, `date1 between date2 and date3` and so on.

You cannot have 'date with format' into the table. If you think so, it means you have varchar field which represents a date. If you wish to compare it, you should convert it to date using `to_date` function.